# How to fetch JSON I created for my React application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, fetch-api

I want to create React base application (the game "worlde") so I can put it on my Git (to make my portfolio). I want to use the `fetch` API, so I created a JSON file with 500 words, but I don't know how to use it. The more I look for solutions, the more confused I get.

Do you know a way (website to upload it or even through `localhost`) to fetch my data?

Thank you!!

Comment: You can import the JSON directly into a React project via `import data from "/path/to/data.json"`

Comment: I did that, but I wasn't able to use `fetch`  and `GET` the data @Mr.Polywhirl

Comment: You don't need to fetch the data if you already have it loaded. You will need to update your question and include the code you currently have. There is no way to know how you are sourcing your data.

Comment: the thing is that i want to `fetch` data on purpose because i want to use this code on my portfolio!I know that it is way easer to do it with `import` but this is not what i am trying to do..

Comment: If you are running a webserver locally (or hosting the file remotely on a public server), you can access the file via GET.

Answer (score 1):

You can read about the [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) API at MDN to know more.
A simple usage example is

```js
fetch('./path/to/data.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
  //You can use the data in anyway you want
   console.log(data);
  });
```